# How to inject CSS with user origin in a browser extension?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, css-cascade

I have a very simple extension:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "User Style Sheet Workaround",
  "version": "1",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css": ["default.css"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want `default.css` to be injected as [user origin, not as author origin](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade). How can I do it?

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.insertCSS with cssOrigin: 'user' in the background script inside a listener for chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted, for example.

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you post an example? Also I would need the "tabs" permission in that case right? Is there any way to do it without requiring any permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [chrome.tabs.insertCSS](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS) with `cssOrigin: 'user'` in the background script's URL change event.

For example, chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted (requires `webNavigation` permission) or chrome.tabs.onUpdated (doesn't require any special permissions).

The target sites to allow CSS injection should be added to `permissions`.

manifest.json:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "User Style Sheet Workaround",
  "version": "1",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

bg.js:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, info) => {
  if (info.status === 'loading') {
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId, {
      file: 'style.css',
      cssOrigin: 'user',
      runAt: 'document_start',
      // allFrames: true,
      // matchAboutBlank: true,
    }, () => chrome.runtime.lastError); // ignoring errors
  }
});
```

Comment: I think the "proper" way is your first suggestion. `tabs.onUpdated` is invoked multiple times per navigation but `webNavigation.onCommitted` is invoked only once. Plus `webNavigation.onCommitted` can accept a filter so that I can more efficiently tell it to run only on "http" and "https" schemes (an error was being thrown when I opened a new tab, since it was trying to run on new tab as well). Hence, that's the best way as far as I can tell, what do you think?

Comment: Of course webNavigation is a cleaner method.

Comment: One problem is, even when using `runAt: 'document_start'`, there is still a very short flash of the website's styles before my style sheet is injected. There was no flash at all when using `content_scripts`. Do you know how can I get rid of this flash? I guess I need the style sheet to be injected even sooner but not sure if it will solve it as well.

Comment: Try using `code` with the contents of the file instead of `file` parameter.

Comment: No difference, and I didn't forget to reload the extension. I guess I have to try to find a way to inject it earlier or simply live with it.

Comment: If you're using it to override page styles then you can probably use *CSS specificity hacks* in a normal author mode style.

Comment: I agree, that's probably the most sensible solution with these circumstances. Still I wonder how come there is no option to programmatically inject something as early as declaratively injecting it.